# How does pandas.qcut deal with remainder values?

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

```
game_num = range(1,102,1)
player_name = ['Fred']*101

dict = {'name':player_name,'game_num':game_num}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df['percentile_bin'] = pd.qcut(df['game_num'],100,list(range(1,101)))
```

- **Problem**

If I enter `df.percentile_bin.nunique()` I get 98 which indicates that 2 percentile bins are not populated.

You can see for instance below, that `game_num` 2 is allocated to the 1st percentile_bin along with  `game_num` 1. Why is this?

I would have expected pd.qcut(100,list(range(1,101))) to allocate 100 percentile bins to this dataframe, each populated by 1 row, with exactly 1 extra (because there was 101 rows).

- **Desired Output**

I really need to 100 bins (percentiles) rather than 98. I don't necessarily have 100 values per individual. Some individuals have 100 values (the minimum), others have 100000s. I would like to reduce each of these individuals values to 100 percentiles which represents their performance over a year in 100 "chunks" or percentiles. (it is hard to specify bin size because I do not know how many total values a given individual may have: 100 or 1000000?)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the rounding error of IEEE 754 floating-point numbers.

This can be seen in the returned bins of the `pandas.qcut()`.

```
cats, bins = pd.qcut(range(1,102,1), 100, retbins=True)
for e in bins:
    print(e)
```

This will output the following.

```
...
28.0
29.000000000000004
29.999999999999996
31.0
...
54.0
56.00000000000001
57.00000000000001
58.00000000000001
58.99999999999999
60.0
...
```

So, the categories(intervals) `(29.000000000000004,29.999999999999996]` and `(58.00000000000001, 58.99999999999999]` will not be in the returned categorical data.

If you want just 100 intervals, you can use `pandas.cut()` like this.

```
cats = pd.cut(range(1, 102), 100)
```

Comment: I really need to 100 bins (percentiles) rather than 98. Is there a way of seeing what the numerator/denominator for each bin? i.e., so I can somehow change the rounding method used? To get exactly 100 percentile bins when I have >100 unique values, I suspect I will need to somehow need to do the binning myself or use an alternative to qcut unless you have any suggestions.

Comment: You cannot control IEEE 754 rounding errors. I'll update the answer for that case.

Comment: The issue with pandas.cut is that I don't necessarily have 100 values per individual.
Some individuals have 100 values (the minimum), others have 100000s.
I would like to reduce each of these individuals values to 100 percentiles which represents their performance over a year. This is why I chose pandas.qcut() instead of pandas.cut() but there remains this issue of founding floating-point numbers.

Comment: You need to be clear. Do you want [quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) or just equally spaced cut points? And do you want categorized values or categories(intervals)? If you want categorized values, is it really matter that a float value such as 29.0 is categorized into the bin#27 or bin#28? That float values will always have a noise/jitter.

Comment: After examining my problem in more detail, I realize that pd.cut() is sufficient and will also more-or-less populate the intervals evenly unlike pd.qcut() IF (and only if) I apply pd.cut() to a column where the values are already ranked intervals that are unique: which applies in my case since the rows are game number (i.e., nth game played).

I am still unclear precisely how IEEE 754 rounding error resulted in particular intervals being omitted but I suspect I will have to look under the hood of qcut(). Thanks!